# A Djangoic method of checking if it is an allowed subdomain

Tags: python, django

I have to solve this little problem in Python/Django and I'm wondering which is the best way to go about it.

I have a list of allowed domains e.g. `www.google.com`, `mail.google.com`. I would like to check if a domain is allowed or not. Now, a request from either `www.google.com` is valid, and a request from `mail.google.com` is valid too.

However, I would like to count `www` as a wildcard which means that if I had the same list of allowed domains as above, A request from `docs.google.com` would be considered valid and so a request from `google.com` even though they don't exist in the list but since `www.google.com` exists and `www.` is a leading wildcard, both domains match.

What would be the best way to implement this? Here's a snippet of mine where I'm trying to implement this:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    url = request.REQUEST['url']
    host = urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc.lower().strip()
    domains = [domain.host.lstrip('www.') for domain in Domain.objects.all()]

    for domain in domains:
        if host.endswith(domain):
            return super(ProcessRequestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

My `Domain` model has just one field, called `host`. This solution of mine make just one DB hit but I'm sure if it's the best or the most efficient.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just store `google.com` in your table of allowed sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if i would like to use wildcard it would not be "www" since www is nothing but a subdomain.

For example if i would like to let all google domains my record would be "**.google.com**".
This would show for example **www.google.com.au** as not allowed. It's possible for you to put wildcard to the end but then **google.com.example.com** would be allowed which is not good idea. Or maybe you would like to allow all UK sites with domain name ending with *co.uk* with "**.co.uk**" record.

Thus you should be looking for subdomains specific to general:

Lest assume the domain name is docs.google.co.uk and you have only the "**.co.uk**" record.

1. Query for docs.google.co.uk - check whether full host name allowed or not.
2. Query for .docs.google.co.uk in case of any wildcard definition
3. Query for .google.co.uk
4. Query for .co.uk - Bingo you find a wildcard, its allowed!

Anyway, in your code you are selecting every domain objects from db and then looking for appropriate domain name with a loop. This operation would unnecessarily slow down your process. Instead of selecting them all you should let database to handle the elimination of not related domains.

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  url = request.REQUEST['url']
  host = urlparse.urlparse(url).netloc.lower().strip()

  domains = Domain.objects.filter(domain=host)
  if len(domains):
    return super(ProcessRequestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  else:
    newHost = '.%s' %host 
    dotPosition = -1
    for i in range(newHost.count('.')):
      dotPosition = newHost.find('.', dotPosition + 1)
      domains = Domain.objects.filter(domain=newHost[dotPosition:])
      if len(domains):
        return super(ProcessRequestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

I hope it will help.